# Rich Text Editor not loading when opened through django server

Tags: html, django, rte

I tried to embed a rich text text editor in my HTML page. The text editor works when the page is loaded seperately. But when I load the page through my django server, the Rich Text Editor does not work. the HTML page:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/aswin/python/myblog/tinymace/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                tinymce.init({
                            selector: "textarea"
                             });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form method="post" action = "/home/add/">
                    <input type = "text" value = "Title" name = "title">
                    <textarea >Hello</textarea>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Post">
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a JavaScript file from location directly on your local hard drive (`/home/aswin/python/myblog/tinymace/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js`). Websites you load from a server (even a Django development server running on your local machine) are not supposed to be able to load files from user's local hard drive, so your browser blocks this.

Please, read about [managing static files through Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to Django documentation on static files.